# C# manipulating video

Tags: c#, video, video-processing, video-encoding

i want to take a folder of pictures, and turn it into a slideshow video with music in the background.

i have no idea how to do this, or where to get help, cos this isnt the kind of thing you can search in google.

idk if there are api's for it, or if it can even be done in C#.

maybe ill have to move the project to C++ or something, but first i need to know where the hell to start.

thanks.

Comment: What video formats are you tagetting? What format is the audio in when you start?

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely the kind of thing you can search in Google.  Try "creating avi files in C#" and pick one of the answers.  I recommend [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/avifilewrapper.aspx) from personal experience.

Creating an AVI file is actually pretty easy - you basically just set a frame rate and dump in a bunch of bitmap files, then add a WAV or MP3 file (or files) for the audio, and that's it.

The AVI file can then be played as is, or compressed into an MPEG or whatever (although you won't get much size compression with a slideshow-type video file, you also don't need it as much).

Comment: Almost seven years later and google isn't giving me much luck. In fact, googling _led me to this answer_. So thanks for that.

Comment: 10 years later google is still not helping me find anything related to video manipulation using C#